# Django ImportError using python3 and compiled mod_wsgi in Centos7

Tags: django, python-3.x, mod-wsgi, importerror, centos7

I have recently setup a new project in Django.  I'm now getting an error in /etc/httpd/logs/error.log:

> [Thu Oct 27 22:43:40.314525 2016] [wsgi:error] [pid 47381] [remote
>   127.0.0.1:52662] ImportError: No module named 'myproject.settings'

I originally completed the polls tutorial, and got it working with:

- Centos7
- Django 1.10
- virtualenv
- Apache 2.4
- MariaDB 10.1.17 (works the same as mysql)
- Python 3.4.3
- mod_wsgi (using yum.  This used python2.7)

This all worked, but I noticed that when I ran this project using the internal webserver

```
./manage.py runserver
```

It used python3.  When I ran this project using apache with mod_wsgi it used python 2.7.  It was fully functional, and all of the webpages worked but they used python2.7.

So I found my error (or one of them) was installing mod_wsgi using yum instead of compiling it from source.

So I uninstalled mod_wsgi using

```
yum remove mod_wsgi
```

I then compiled mod_wsgi from source using

```
wget "https://github.com/GrahamDumpleton/mod_wsgi/archive/4.5.7.tar.gz"
tar -xzf '4.5.7.tar.gz'
cd ./mod_wsgi-4.5.7
./configure --with-python=/bin/python3.4
make
make install
```

I then had to add a line to /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf:

```
LoadModule wsgi_module modules/mod_wsgi.so
```

When I now try to run this, I get the ImportError message above.  My wsgi.py file is:

```
import os

from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application

os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "myproject.settings")

application = get_wsgi_application()
```

For debugging, I have replaced my wsgi.py file with:

```
import sys

def application(environ, start_response):
    status = '200 OK'

    output = ''
    output += 'sys.version = %s\n' % repr(sys.version)
    output += 'sys.prefix = %s\n' % repr(sys.prefix)
    output += 'sys.path = %s\n' % repr(sys.path)
    output += 'mod_wsgi.process_group = %s\n' % repr(environ['mod_wsgi.process_group'])
    output += 'mod_wsgi.application_group = %s\n' % repr(environ['mod_wsgi.application_group'])

    response_headers = [('Content-type', 'text/plain'),
                        ('Content-Length', str(len(output)))]
    start_response(status, response_headers)

    return [str.encode(output)]
```

to give me the output:

> sys.version = '3.4.3 (default, Aug  9 2016, 17:10:39) \n[GCC 4.8.5
>   20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-4)]' sys.prefix = '/usr' sys.path =
>   ['/home/myuser/myproject',
>   '/home/myuser/myproject/myprojectenv/lib/python3.4/site-packages',
>   '/usr/lib64/python34.zip', '/usr/lib64/python3.4',
>   '/usr/lib64/python3.4/plat-linux', '/usr/lib64/python3.4/lib-dynload',
>   '/usr/lib64/python3.4/site-packages',
>   '/usr/lib/python3.4/site-packages'] mod_wsgi.process_group =
>   'myproject' mod_wsgi.application_group = 'localhost.localdomain|'

I've been through the django documentation, as well as the mod_wsgi documentation and can't seem to find what my problem is.

My httpd config is  /etc/httpd/config.d/django.conf:

```
Alias /static /home/myuser/myproject/static
<Directory /home/myuser/myproject/static>
    Require all granted
</Directory>

<Directory /home/myuser/myproject/myproject>
    <Files wsgi.py>
        Require all granted
    </Files>
</Directory>

WSGIDaemonProcess myproject python-path=/home/myuser/myproject:/home/myuser/myproject/myprojectenv/lib/python3.4/site-packages
WSGIProcessGroup myproject
WSGIScriptAlias / /home/myuser/myproject/myproject/wsgi.py
```

My project is using the standard file structure from the django tutorial:

- /home/myuser/myproject/myproject/wsgi.py

The static files still are being served properly through apache.  Any ideas?

Comment: What is the full path to the ``settings.py`` file? Do directories/files have permissions such that the Apache user (not you), could read them.

Comment: Thanks for having a look Graham.  I've seen your name on lots of these Django posts.

-rw-rw-r--   /home/myuser/myproject/myproject/settings.py

permissions work for apache.  This worked successfully with mod_wsgi (installed by yum using python2.7)  It only stopped working when I compiled mod_wsgi from source using python 3.4.

Comment: In the test WSGI application, do ``import myproject``. See if that works and if it does what value does ``myproject.__file__`` have?

Comment: Done.  The output is:

myproject.__file__ = '/home/myuser/myproject/myproject/__init__.py'

Comment: If ``settings.py`` is in that same directory, makes no sense why it wouldn't be found.

Comment: Yes, settings.py is in the same directory.  Thanks for your investigations.
I just removed my compiled version of mod_wsgi by using: rm /etc/httpd/modules/mod_wsgi.so  I then ran yum install mod_wsgi, and it works.  But it is running python 2.7.  Obviously my problem is in the way I am compiling/installing mod_wsgi, or with something else that needs to be changed at the same time?

Comment: As a follow-up, I've re-installed everything.  I believe that an error was made in the version of pip I originally installed.  A clean install fixed my problem.  During the re-install, I also switched to python 3.5 and Django 1.11.